# Add attachment to email does not work

Tags: vb.net, email

I have been searching this forum and others and so far have not had any success getting an attachment to work from my code. I need to use "mail to" as I have no idea what email client the user may have, my system that I am testing on uses Outlook 2013. If their client does not support programmatically added attachments, I have a note in the body on how to do it manually. Where possible I would like to add the attachment myself. Here is my code:

```
Public Function OpenEmail(ByVal EmailAddress As String, ByVal Subject As String,
    Optional ByVal Body As String = "", Optional ByVal Attachment As String = "") As Boolean

    Dim bAns As Boolean = True
    Dim sParams As String

    bAns = True

    sParams = EmailAddress

    If (LCase(Strings.Left(sParams, 7)) <> "mailto:") Then

        sParams = "mailto:" & sParams

    End If

    'There will always be a Subject line
    sParams = sParams & "?subject=" & Subject

    If (Body <> "") Then

        sParams = sParams & "&body=" & Body

    End If

    If (Attachment <> "") Then

        'sParams = sParams & "&attachment=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Attachment & Chr(34) & Chr(34)

        'sParams = sParams & "&attachment=" & Chr(34) & Attachment & Chr(34)

        'sParams = sParams & "&attachment=" & Attachment

        sParams = sParams & "&attach=" & Attachment

    End If

    'Change " " space characters to HTML format
    sParams = Replace(sParams, " ", "%20")

    'Change "'" apostrophe characters to HTML format
    sParams = Replace(sParams, " ", "%27")

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sParams)

End Function
```

Comment: What mail-format is that? Are you trying a mime-attach?

Comment: The format, if I understand your question, is the generic internet email format. I am not trying to use mime-attach.